# how to return string id from insert stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to return a string id after the insert statement runs in a stored procedure.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_quote(
    p_id character varying(40),
    p_name character varying(200),
    p_website character varying(200),
    p_phone character varying(100),
    p_email character varying(200),
    p_msg text,
    p_created_on timestamp without time zone,
    p_created_ip cidr,
    p_contacted boolean,
    p_contacted_on timestamp without time zone
)
RETURNS character varying(40) AS $body$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO quote VALUES (p_id, p_name, p_website, p_phone, p_email, p_msg, p_created_on, p_created_ip, p_contacted, p_contacted_on)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
       DO UPDATE SET name = p_name, website = p_website, phone = p_phone, email = p_email, msg = p_msg, created_on = p_created_on, created_ip = p_created_ip, contacted 
= p_contacted, contacted_on = p_contacted_on RETURNING id;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The table schema:

```
                               Table "public.quote"
    Column    |            Type             |              Modifiers               
--------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------
 id           | character varying(40)       | not null
 name         | character varying(200)      | not null
 website      | character varying(200)      | not null
 phone        | character varying(100)      | not null
 email        | character varying(200)      | not null
 msg          | text                        | 
 created_on   | timestamp without time zone | default timezone('utc'::text, now())
 created_ip   | cidr                        | 
 contacted    | boolean                     | 
 contacted_on | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "quote_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "quote_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
```

Here is the error I get when I try to call the procedure from the psql client.

```
select * from create_quote("qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1", "name", "website", "phone", "email", "msg", now()::timestamp, NULL, 0, now()::timestamp);
ERROR:  column "qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from create_quote("qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q...
```

I am a bit confused as I am not passing in a column and just a string `id` for the first parameter. What am I doing wrong?

I made the changes that clemens mentioned below but now i am getting this error:

```
select create_quote('qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1', 'name', 'website', 'phone', 'email', 'msg', now()::timestamp, NULL, 0, now()::timestamp);
ERROR:  function create_quote(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, timestamp without time zone, unknown, integer, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: select create_quote('qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1', 'na...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Thanks

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

1. String in SQL are limited with single quotes. Double quotes are there to protect identifiers (e.g. case sensitive column names). Use `'qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1'` instead of `"qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1"` for instance.
2. Your function is returning a scalar and not a set. You shouldn't call it from the `FROM` clause.

   ```
   SELECT create_quote('qw2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1', 'name', 'website', 'phone', 'email', 'msg', now()::timestamp, NULL, 0, now()::timestamp);
   ```
3. Your function doesn't return a value. You can assign the result from the *UPSERT* to a variable and returning this. Or much easier returning the input parameter `p_id`, because your *UPSERT* will always return this value.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_quote(
       p_id character varying(40),
       p_name character varying(200),
       p_website character varying(200),
       p_phone character varying(100),
       p_email character varying(200),
       p_msg text,
       p_created_on timestamp without time zone,
       p_created_ip cidr,
       p_contacted boolean,
       p_contacted_on timestamp without time zone

   )
   RETURNS character varying(40) AS $body$
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO quote VALUES (p_id, p_name, p_website, p_phone, p_email, p_msg, p_created_on, p_created_ip, p_contacted, p_contacted_on)
       ON CONFLICT (id)
           DO UPDATE SET name = p_name, website = p_website, phone = p_phone, email = p_email, msg = p_msg, created_on = p_created_on, created_ip = p_created_ip, contacted 
   = p_contacted, contacted_on = p_contacted_on;
       RETURN p_id;
   END;
   $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```

Comment: thanks for your response, i made all those changes but now i am getting a different response, i updated the ticket towards the bottom

Comment: this helped me, i had to change the 0 to FALSE and pass in a string ip address, thanks